# How to select elements of delimited string?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco)
>   [Split Function equivalent in tsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)
>   [How Do I Split a Delimited String in SQL Server Without Creating a Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722700/how-do-i-split-a-delimited-string-in-sql-server-without-creating-a-function)

Let's say I have a varchar with the following value:

```
'1:2:3:4:5'
```

I would like to write a select statement, with the result of:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Many dups if you search for *[t-sql] split* E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco

Comment: See this duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/3097864/175679 using XML or UDF