# How to split a comma separated data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a procedure and input is comma separated like '1,2,3'.

I would like to query like

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE PERSON_ID IN(1,2,3).
```

Please note that PERSON_ID is integer.

Comment: Then there is no question, just don't enclose the input string within a pair of single quotes.

Comment: You can use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3097916/1114171) and then do `IN (SELECT * FROM @xml)`

Comment: Hi Lion, My code is like .                                       DECLARE @T AS STRING
SET @T='1,2,3'

SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE PERSON_ID IN(@T). Could you please help to modify this?

Comment: There is a logical difference between 3 integers separated by commas, and a single string that happens to *contain* commas. SQL (along with every other sane language I've ever encountered) doesn't magically decide to inspect the interior of the string, spot commas, and decide to convert between the two. (And if it did, how would you search if you were searching for a column value that actually *did* contain a comma?)

Comment: The ideal situation is to switch from passing comma separated values in the first place to instead passing a table-valued parameter (or xml). But either way, please search this site or google. This question has been asked *so many* times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string in database row and copy results to different rows - SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097864/split-string-in-database-row-and-copy-results-to-different-rows-sql-server)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split Function equivalent in tsql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this type of question so often I posted a blog on it [here.](http://sqlstudies.com/2013/04/08/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-an-in-clause/)

Basically you have three options (to the best of my knowledge)

The `LIKE` version that Gordon Lindoff suggested.

Using a split function like so.

```
DECLARE @InList varchar(100)
SET @InList = '1,2,3,4'

SELECT MyTable.*
FROM MyTable
JOIN DelimitedSplit8K (@InList,',') SplitString
    ON MyTable.Id = SplitString.Item
```

Or using dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @InList varchar(100)
SET @InList = '1,2,3,4'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * ' + 
            'FROM MyTable ' + 
            'WHERE Id IN ('+@InList+') '

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchList = ',' + inputSearchTerm + ',';  /* e.g. inputSearchTerm is '1,2,3' */

SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE CONTAINS(SearchList, ',' + cast(PERSON_ID as varchar) + ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `contains` seems like overkill (it is designed for fuzzy searching and uses a full text index), because `charindex()` is not standard SQL, and I abhor answers where `varchar` does not have length, let me give an alternative:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON
WHERE ','+@SearchList+',' like '%,'+cast(PERSON_ID as varchar(255))+',%';
```

The concatenation of commas for `@SearchList` makes sure that all values are surrounded by delimiters.  These are then put around the particular value, to prevent `1` from matching `10`.

Note that this will *not* be particularly efficient, because it will require a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it using a recursive CTE:

```
declare @SearchList varchar(20)
set @SearchList= '1,2,3'
;with cte as
(select case charindex(',',@SearchList)
            when 0 then cast(@SearchList as int)
            else cast(left(@SearchList,charindex(',',@SearchList)-1) as int)
        end searchVal,
        case charindex(',',@SearchList)
            when 0 then ''
            else right(@SearchList,
                       len(@SearchList)-charindex(',',@SearchList) )
        end remainStr
 union all
 select case charindex(',',remainStr)
            when 0 then cast(remainStr as int)
            else cast(left(remainStr,charindex(',',remainStr)-1) as int)
        end searchVal,
        case charindex(',',remainStr)
            when 0 then ''
            else right(remainStr,
                       len(remainStr)-charindex(',',remainStr) )
        end remainStr
 from cte
 where remainStr > ''
)
select p.* 
from cte
join person p on cte.searchVal = p.person_id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19813/12).